# Chacek box logic (Written in jquery) is not working for the first time of the scenario

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with a jquery code block.
I have a simple jsp page and there is a search button to search a particular item. When you click that search button an ajax request gets called based on the item id you have given into that field, then it retrieves the informations from server and populates other fields on that page.
Now there is a field for price and there is a checkbox along with it.
My logic (jquery) requires that when the price is not 0, then the price will be displayed in the price field, checkbox will be checked and also on that jsp page, the price should get written in a specific place.
but my problem is, if price is not 0, then checkbox is checked and also price is getting written on the page, but if I then uncheck the checkbox, the price shouldn't get displayed on that page anymore which is not happening for the first time (after the page is loaded) when I uncheck the checkbox. but if then I check again and then uncheck again then it is working fine, like getting displayed if the checkbox is checked, is not getting displayed if the checkbox is unchecked.
So the issue is logic is not working when I attempt first time to uncheck the checkbox.
I am facing the issue only in IE (version 8), not in Mozilla.
here is the code snippet for your better understanding...

**sample.jsp**

```
<table id="item_search">
<tr><td><label>Item Id : </label></td><td><input type="text" id="item_id"   name="item_id"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="item_search" value="item Info"></td>
```

```
<tr><td><label>Price :</label></td>
<td ><input type="text" id="item_price" name="item_price"><input type="checkbox" id="item_isprice" name="item_isprice"></input></td>
<legend>Label</legend>
<div id="label_preview">
<div class="price"> </div>
```

**sample.js**

```
$("#item_search").bind("click",function() 
{$.getJSON("----some url-----",
{
       id : $("#item_id").val(),
}, iteminforeturn);
});

$("#item_isprice").change(refreshlabel);

function iteminforeturn(json) {
   $("#item_price").val(json['price']);
   refreshlabelFirst();
}

function refreshlabelFirst(event){
if($("#item_price").val() != 0 ){
    $("#item_isprice").attr("checked",true);
    $("#label_preview .price").html("price : " + $("#item_price").val());
} else {
    $("#item_isprice").attr("checked",false);
    $("#label_preview .price").html("");
}
 }

function refreshlabel(event) {
    if($("item_price").val() != "" && $('#item_isprice').is(':checked')){
    $("#label_preview .price").html("price In : " + $("#item_price").val());
} else {
    $("#label_preview .price").html("");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, these won't do what you expect:

```
attr('checked', true)
attr('checked', false)
```

Instead you just need to replace those statements with:

```
attr('checked', 'checked')
removeAttr('checked')
```

If you're using jQuery 1.6 or higher, you can also use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Did you try this out, Ani? Any problems?

Comment: It is not working. The problem still persists. And the problem is happening for the very first time when that module is being called.I must say again that it is perfect in Firefox. thank you for looking into my issue.

Comment: Could you set up a live version (jsFiddle or CodePen)? That will make it much easier for the SO community to help out.

Comment: ok..let me try Jamie. But what i have described here is a bit difficult for me to replicate on jsfiddle.

Comment: and also Jamie can you please tell me why this problem can occur?i mean what can be the reason, because that might help me to solve out the issue. thank you

Comment: Outside of using the right command to toggle the checkbox's state, I don't know. But I bet with a fiddle set up — that replicates the issue with as little code as possible — someone smarter than I could figure it out quickly.